# Command Line Installation with SCCM 2012

Tags: batch-file, deployment, automation, windows-server-2008, sccm

I have a few applications that I am trying to deploy with SCCM 2012 but the installations are failing through the application catalog. So what I have for the deployment type is a script installer. I have "cmd.exe" (Without quotations) in the Installation program field and "Installer.bat" in the installation start in field.

When I look at the ccmcache folder, all the contents over that application are there but the following error displays the Software Center:

```
 0x8007010B(-217024629)
```

I have done some reading online and the "10B" is a common command line error for invalid directory. I have tested the batch file when hard coding a path but my question is, how can I edit the batch file or SCCM to pull from the CCMCache path where the files are downloaded to on the local client? Currently the Batch File is simply:

```
 @echo off
 ApplicationName.exe
```

Do I need to edit the file to cd into the CCMCache folder where the files are placed? How can I get the batch file to run the executable that is downloaded to the CCMCache folder?

Thank You!

Comment: The batch file does not know where the `.exe` is, so you have to tell it, 1. by adding the path to the `.exe` to the system's `PATH` variable, or 2. by explicitly changing to the containing directory, using `cd /D`, or 3. by calling the `.exe` via its full path, like `"D:\path\to\CCMChache\folder\ApplicationName.exe"`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The CCMCache folder always changes. How can I hardcode that in?

Comment: I see. Can you query the location somehow? Or is there only one `CCMCache` folder, so it could be searched by the script? Or, in case there could be more than one, would it be fine to use the one containing the most recent `.exe` file?

Comment: There is  only one CCMCache folder but each subfolder is different. We have a folder that comes with our image so each machine in our environment has it. Is there a way in SCCM to tell it to download and place the required files in a different location?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with SCCM, I can only help with the batch-file part...

Comment: I am not sure I understand this correctly. Normally if ApplicationName.exe is part of your source sccm will always download it in the same folder as your bat so the relative paths should work in a ways that if the bat can run from your source it will also run from your ccmcache. So I would check the sccm settings if something is wrong there rather than fiddle with the bat. If you really want to change the bat the variable %~dp0 will give you the path the batch file is executed from so from there you could construct an absolute path that is still dependent on the location it is run from

Comment: So do I need the batch file? If I just set the deployment to point to the exe, is a batch file necessary?

Comment: If you just want to execute one setup with parameters you don't need any sort of script. You only need a bat (or vbs or ps1) if you want to change stuff before or after the setup or need some complicated conditions. If you don't sccm can execute any setup just fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the full path to the installation in your script

@echo Off

\\path to .exe

The way the command is written will not be able to find the .exe file.  You need to add the full unc path to the .exe into your .cmd file.  You should have your installation .exe and .cmd file in the same location on the distribution share

Answer (score 0):

***Recommended Solution:***

Before starting, since you are only launching an exe with your batch file, I would recommend just using your ApplicationName.exe as your command line parameter in SCCM instead of using a batch.  This will eliminate the need to engineer any further.

***Modifying the existing solution to work:***

If you do still want to use a batch file, keep a few things in mind.  The syntax you are using to launch the batch file will not work.  I would recommend just using the batch file name "installer.bat" as your command line.  If you still want to preface the batch with the cmd.exe, you absolutely need to use the /c switch with it

```
cmd.exe /c installer.bat
```

If you don't use /c the console host will only open to a promopt and not execute your batch.

This is not an ideal solution though because using "cmd.exe /c" will set your working directory to the location of cmd.exe (ie "C:\windows\system32") and since your content is staged in ccmcache, you will need to specify its location within your batch.  To do this, you would use %~dp0 variable which gives you the directory the current batch is running from.  This means modifying your batch to read

```
@echo off
%~dp0ApplicationName.exe
```